# How to remove the sketch for the LCD and retaining the sketch for the MPU6050?

Tags: arduino-uno, mpu6050

I just got this from the internet and I only want to use the sketch for the MPU6050. Can someone help me to remove the code for the LCD? I'm sorry, I'm just noob when it comes to programming.

Here is my source: [Earthquake Detector using Arduino and MPU-6050](http://microcontrollerslab.com/earthquake-detector-arduino/)

Here is the sketch:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

#include <Wire.h>

#include <MPU6050.h>

#define minval -5

#define maxval 3

MPU6050 mpu;

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup()

{   lcd.begin(16, 2);

Serial.begin(115200);

pinMode(7,OUTPUT);

pinMode(8,OUTPUT);

lcd.print("   EarthQuake ");

lcd.setCursor(0, 1);

lcd.print("   Detector");

delay (2000);

lcd.clear();

// Initialize MPU6050

Serial.println("Initialize MPU6050");

while(!mpu.begin(MPU6050_SCALE_2000DPS, MPU6050_RANGE_2G))

{ Serial.println("Could not find a valid MPU6050 sensor, check wiring!");

delay(500);}

mpu.setThreshold(3); 

// Check settings

checkSettings();

}



void checkSettings()

{

Serial.println();



Serial.print(" * Sleep Mode:        ");

Serial.println(mpu.getSleepEnabled() ? "Enabled" : "Disabled");

Serial.print(" * Clock Source:      ");

switch(mpu.getClockSource())

{case MPU6050_CLOCK_KEEP_RESET:     Serial.println("Stops the clock and 
keeps the timing generator in reset"); break;

case MPU6050_CLOCK_EXTERNAL_19MHZ: Serial.println("PLL with external 
19.2MHz reference"); break;

case MPU6050_CLOCK_EXTERNAL_32KHZ: Serial.println("PLL with external         
32.768kHz reference"); break;

case MPU6050_CLOCK_PLL_ZGYRO:      Serial.println("PLL with Z axis 
gyroscope reference"); break;

case MPU6050_CLOCK_PLL_YGYRO:      Serial.println("PLL with Y axis 
gyroscope reference"); break;

case MPU6050_CLOCK_PLL_XGYRO:      Serial.println("PLL with X axis 
gyroscope reference"); break;

case MPU6050_CLOCK_INTERNAL_8MHZ:  Serial.println("Internal 8MHz 
oscillator"); break;

}

Serial.print(" * Gyroscope:         ");

switch(mpu.getScale())

{case MPU6050_SCALE_2000DPS:        Serial.println("2000 dps"); break;

case MPU6050_SCALE_1000DPS:        Serial.println("1000 dps"); break;

case MPU6050_SCALE_500DPS:         Serial.println("500 dps"); break;

case MPU6050_SCALE_250DPS:         Serial.println("250 dps"); break:}

Serial.print(" * Gyroscope offsets: ");

Serial.print(mpu.getGyroOffsetX());

Serial.print(" / ");

Serial.print(mpu.getGyroOffsetY());

Serial.print(" / ");

Serial.println(mpu.getGyroOffsetZ());

Serial.println();}

void loop()

{   Vector rawGyro = mpu.readRawGyro();

Vector normGyro = mpu.readNormalizeGyro();

Serial.print(" Xraw = ");

Serial.print(rawGyro.XAxis);

Serial.print(" Yraw = ");

Serial.print(rawGyro.YAxis);

Serial.print(" Zraw = ");

Serial.println(rawGyro.ZAxis); 

if(normGyro.XAxis > maxval || normGyro.XAxis < minval && normGyro.YAxis > 
maxval || normGyro.YAxis  < minval && normGyro.ZAxis > maxval || 
normGyro.ZAxis  < minval)

{ digitalWrite(7,HIGH);

digitalWrite(8,HIGH);

delay(300);

digitalWrite(7,HIGH);

digitalWrite(8,HIGH);

delay(300);

lcd.clear();

lcd.print("***EarthQuake***");

delay (1000);

lcd.clear();}

else{digitalWrite(7,LOW);

digitalWrite(8,LOW);}

Serial.print(" Xnorm = ");

Serial.print(normGyro.XAxis);

Serial.print(" Ynorm = ");

Serial.print(normGyro.YAxis);

Serial.print(" Znorm = ");

Serial.println(normGyro.ZAxis);

delay(10);}
```

Comment: Delete all the lines that have "lcd" in them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Majenko states, carefully remove all lines with the `lcd` object in them. Due to the extremely poor formatting and indentation of the code, if you aren't careful you could lose some important syntax, such as the `{` and `}`.

Also, there is no need for the `LiquidCrystal` header file.

In addition, there is a typo in the posted code (it is beyond me why the author would post uncompilable (and hence untested) code), in this line:

```
case MPU6050_SCALE_250DPS:         Serial.println("250 dps"); break:}
```

Here is the code with the `lcd` related lines stripped out, correctly formatted and indented, with the typo fixed:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <MPU6050.h>

#define minval -5
#define maxval 3

MPU6050 mpu;


void setup()
{       
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);

  delay (2000);

  // Initialize MPU6050
  Serial.println("Initialize MPU6050");

  while(!mpu.begin(MPU6050_SCALE_2000DPS, MPU6050_RANGE_2G))
  { 
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid MPU6050 sensor, check wiring!");
    delay(500);
  }

  mpu.setThreshold(3); 
  // Check settings
  checkSettings();
}



void checkSettings()
{
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print(" * Sleep Mode:        ");
  Serial.println(mpu.getSleepEnabled() ? "Enabled" : "Disabled");
  Serial.print(" * Clock Source:      ");
  switch(mpu.getClockSource())
  {
    case MPU6050_CLOCK_KEEP_RESET:
      Serial.println("Stops the clock and keeps the timing generator in reset"); 
      break;
    case MPU6050_CLOCK_EXTERNAL_19MHZ:
      Serial.println("PLL with external 19.2MHz reference"); 
      break;
    case MPU6050_CLOCK_EXTERNAL_32KHZ:
      Serial.println("PLL with external 32.768kHz reference");
      break;
    case MPU6050_CLOCK_PLL_ZGYRO:
      Serial.println("PLL with Z axis gyroscope reference");
      break;
    case MPU6050_CLOCK_PLL_YGYRO:
      Serial.println("PLL with Y axis gyroscope reference");
      break;
    case MPU6050_CLOCK_PLL_XGYRO:
      Serial.println("PLL with X axis gyroscope reference");
      break;
    case MPU6050_CLOCK_INTERNAL_8MHZ:
      Serial.println("Internal 8MHz oscillator"); 
      break;
  }

  Serial.print(" * Gyroscope:         ");
  switch(mpu.getScale())
  {
    case MPU6050_SCALE_2000DPS:
      Serial.println("2000 dps");
      break;
    case MPU6050_SCALE_1000DPS:
      Serial.println("1000 dps");
      break;
    case MPU6050_SCALE_500DPS:
       Serial.println("500 dps");
       break;
    case MPU6050_SCALE_250DPS:
       Serial.println("250 dps");
       break;
  }

  Serial.print(" * Gyroscope offsets: ");
  Serial.print(mpu.getGyroOffsetX());
  Serial.print(" / ");
  Serial.print(mpu.getGyroOffsetY());
  Serial.print(" / ");
  Serial.println(mpu.getGyroOffsetZ());
  Serial.println();
}

void loop()
{
  Vector rawGyro = mpu.readRawGyro();
  Vector normGyro = mpu.readNormalizeGyro();
  Serial.print(" Xraw = ");
  Serial.print(rawGyro.XAxis);
  Serial.print(" Yraw = ");
  Serial.print(rawGyro.YAxis);
  Serial.print(" Zraw = ");
  Serial.println(rawGyro.ZAxis); 

  if (normGyro.XAxis > maxval ||
      normGyro.XAxis < minval &&
      normGyro.YAxis > maxval ||
      normGyro.YAxis < minval &&
      normGyro.ZAxis > maxval || 
      normGyro.ZAxis < minval)
  {
    digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
    delay(300);
    digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
    delay(300);
    delay (1000);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(7,LOW);
    digitalWrite(8,LOW);
  }
  Serial.print(" Xnorm = ");
  Serial.print(normGyro.XAxis);
  Serial.print(" Ynorm = ");
  Serial.print(normGyro.YAxis);
  Serial.print(" Znorm = ");
  Serial.println(normGyro.ZAxis);
  delay(10);
}
```

The page that you got your code from does not specify which MPU6050 library to use. It is not the library by Jeff Rowberg, as linked to from the Arduino Playground, [MPU-6050 Accelerometer + Gyro](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050). It is in fact this library, [MPU6050 Triple Axis Gyroscope & Accelerometer Arduino Library](https://github.com/jarzebski/Arduino-MPU6050).

Comment: Thank you dude! Let me try your recommendation. I'll give some feedback later :D

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to upvote *and* mark the answer as accepted (using the little green tick), if it helps you. Cheers.

Comment: @HamdanieImpa - don't forget to upvote